# Is there a socket.io port to Dart?

Tags: websocket, socket.io, real-time, dart

I've taken a look at the basic websocket capabilities in Dart, using this simple example: 
https://github.com/financeCoding/chat-websocket-dart

But I was wondering if there's a nice library I could use to build a realtime online game using websockets. I've had experience in this using node.js with socket.io, which worked out quite well. I need to be able to have "rooms", join rooms, leave rooms, broadcast to clients in a room, etc. as well as some nice notion of connection "health", reconnection etc. So what I'm asking is if there's a nice library for dart that has similar functionality? Even cooler would be a library on top of that library that could enable nice RPC functionality with variable syncing etc. such as http://nowjs.com/ which achieves this using socket.io. But I guess that might be too ambitious.

If anyone's had any experience or found a project which is similar to what I'm talking about, let me know :)

Answer (score 11):

Duct is clone of Socket.IO in Dart which aims to be protocol-level compatible with the original implementation.

https://github.com/petrhosek/duct

Comment: looks like the package is dead. It wasn't even added to the pub repository

Comment: This package is deeply dead

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, at the time of this writing, I'm not aware of a socket.io port for Dart. socket.io is nice because it has a bunch of implementation options for browsers that don't support Web sockets.

Sounds like a good idea for a hackathon project!

Comment: The thing is Dart is targeting browsers that all support Websockets.. so having support for all the other transports wouldn't be that useful.  The only thing that would be useful is the namespacing SocketIO 0.7+ supports.  And the Duct port seems to have implemented that.

Comment: @abourget wrong, IE9 has no support for WS. I ended up building a comet fallback for our app.